# Isometry Eigenvalues in a Nonsingular Metric Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Let $k$ be a field such that $\mathrm{char}\;k \neq 2$. Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space equipped with a bilinear form $p : V \times V \to k, p:(v,u) \mapsto \langle v, u\rangle$. I say that $V$ is non-singular if for every vector $v \in V$ such that $v\neq 0$ there are $u \in V$ such that $\langle v,u\rangle \neq 0$. Note, that there still can exist a non-zero $v\in V$ such that $\langle v,v\rangle = 0$. For example, consider $p$ defined by the matrix

$$
p \cong
\left[
\begin{array}[cc]
00 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
.
$$

Define the isometry group $\mathbf{Iso}(V)$ as a group of all invertible linear operators $T$ such that $\langle Tv, Tv \rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$. It is known that for a normal Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$, all eigenvalues of the operator $T \in \mathbf{Iso}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathbf{O}(\mathbb{R},n)$ belong to the set $\{-1,1\}$. Is this true that, in general, for every nonsingular $V$ and $T \in \mathbf{Iso}(V)$, I will have eigenvalues of $T$ in $\{-1,1\}$? Obviously, the classical proof translates to any anisotropic space.

My work so far: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T \in \mathbf{Iso}(V)$, I can find an eigenvector $v \neq 0$, such that $T(v) = \lambda v$. It is also possible to find $w = 0$ such that $\langle v,w \rangle \neq 0$, as $V$ is non-singular. Let $u = T^{-1}w$. Then,

$$ 
\lambda\langle v, w \rangle = 
\langle Tv, w \rangle =
\langle Tv, Tu \rangle = 
\langle  v, u \rangle.  
$$

So, $ v \bot \lambda w - u   $. But I don't know how to use this fact. I also failed to construct any counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $O$ for an orthogonal group is reserved for the case that the bilinear form is symmetric; if it's skew-symmetric you get a symplectic group, and if it's neither you get a mix.

Here's a counterexample which is symmetric. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$ and consider $W = V \oplus V^{\ast}$ equipped with the bilinear form

$$B((v_1, f_1), (v_2, f_2)) = f_2(v_1) + f_1(v_2).$$

Then $GL(V)$ embeds into $O(W)$.

Comment: Thanks, you really saved from some futile proof attempts. If the embedding you are talking is $A \mapsto (A^{-1},A^*)$, then it actually works. For my example bilinear form operators of the form $\left[\begin{array}[cc] & \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha^{-1} \end{array}\right]$ are isometries, for example, and their eigenvalues can be any paired values $\alpha, \alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: @Nik: I use $A \mapsto (A, (A^{\ast})^{-1})$ but it's the same.